# Flutter MVVM with provider view-modal constructer calls only one time : Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mvvm, provider, flutter-provider

I'm building an application in Flutter MVVM with provider(using statelesswidget only) . In that i'm facing one issue like, I have 2 screen Login and Registration.

So in LoginViewModal class I did like below

```
class LoginViewModal extends ChangeNotifier {
 LoginViewModal() {
    print("Login View Modal");
    _userName = TextEditingController(text: "");
    _password = TextEditingController(text: "");
  }

  late TextEditingController _userName;
  late TextEditingController _password;
}
```

And for CreateAccountViewModal class I did like below

```
class CreateAccountViewModal extends ChangeNotifier {
 CreateAccountViewModal() {
    print("Create Account View Modal");
    _name = TextEditingController(text: "");
    _mobile = TextEditingController(text: "");
  }

  late TextEditingController _name;
  late TextEditingController _mobile;
}
```

So user entered some data in login screen and switch to createAccount screen but old entered data not cleared. So i need to clear the data when page loads.

I noticed that, constructer prints comes only one time.
I tried lagy:false also

main.dart file

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => LoginViewModal()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => CreateAccountViewModal()),
      ],
      child: ....
   );
  }
}
```

Can any one help me how to reset data on page loads?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I think the best idea is to create a function called resetData() inside the view model and just call that function whenever you want.

Comment: I am using statelesswidget, so where i call the resetData()  ?

Comment: You should handle it inside the provider and then with notifyListener you update the state

Comment: I tried, but i couldn't find solution. can you share some synonyms like how to implement ?